# JavaScript every() on array of object doesn't loop through all the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

This is my code, I'm using this method to validate https request parameters. Logging the entries I see that just the first element of 2 is passed and therefore not all the values are checked. What am I missing?

```
    static validateParameters(req) {
        let params = Object.entries(req.query);

        return params.every(([key, value]) => {
          console.log(key, value);
          return value != undefined || value != ''
        });

    }
```

Edit
The input to the function is a https request, the parameters would be in a 2d array

```
[
  [ 'ids', '' ],
  [ 'currencies', 'eur' ]
]
```

I believed the return value was undefined, but was actually an empty string. In any case changing || to && solved it.

Comment: Is the second value `undefined`, `null`, or an empty string? What are all the values?

Comment: what is your input to the function?

Comment: `every()` stops as soon as the callback function fails, because it doesn't need to check the rest to know that the result is `false`.

Comment: Try adding a null check as well. Something like this: ````return (value != undefined || value != '' || value != null)````

Comment: @SrikarPhaniKumarMarti `value != undefined` will also check for `null`, so it's redundant to check twice.

Comment: What values are not checked? from your input everything is checked

Answer (score 0):

As the [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#description) explains:

> The every() method is an iterative method. It calls a provided callbackFn function once for each element in an array, until the callbackFn returns a falsy value. If such an element is found, every() immediately returns false and stops iterating through the array. Otherwise, if callbackFn returns a truthy value for all elements, every() returns true.

In other words, the 'every' method iteration stops when it gets to the first falsy return (if it exists), therefore, the callbackFn is not called for the remaining elements.